# Media query not working when I change the screen size

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here's the CSS of div I am trying to get to change on max width 800px. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, the same query of max  width works for other container divs.

```
  @media(min-width :800px){
    .bodyForClient{
      background: black;
      height: 2000px;
    }
  }



  .bodyForClient{
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(80, 74, 5, 0.802);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
   
}
```

Comment: On wider screens you set the bodyForClient background and height in a media query and then immediately unset them. media queries do not bump up the selectivity. Try swapping the two round so that media query comes after the .bodyForClient 'standard' setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things I noticed.

1. You put media query on top but it should have on bottom.
2. As you mentioned you want to get a interaction on max-width of 800px but in media query you put min-width so it's working just opposite.

You can apply like this.

It'll apply from (your screen resolution) to 801px.

```
.bodyForClient{
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(80, 74, 5, 0.802);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and it will for 800px and below screens

```
@media(max-width:800px){
.bodyForClient{
      background: black;
      height: 50vh;
    }
}
```

Here you go: https://codepen.io/jskrishna/pen/ZEvNQNW